# Web Page Expiration

Tags: codeigniter

How can I let a user click a link to a page and only have viewing access to that page for one hour?

At the end of the hour, I'd want to either close the tab/window or send the user to another page.

I'm using CodeIgniter as my framework.

How can this be done?

Comment: How do you plan to prevent screenshot/printing?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not put a meta refresh in your view that will move the user along to what ever page you want?

Something along these lines:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600; url=http://example.com/">
```

If you were looking to close the window / tab I suppose you could use a little javascript

```
<script>
    setTimeout(360000, function(){
        window.top.close();
    });
</script>
```

Forgive me if that script doesn't do exactly what it should, it's been a very long time since I used anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be doing using cookies. The idea is that a cookie is created with an access token that you store in your database with a timestamp.

So, when a user gets access to your database, you create a random string and insert it to a database. With CodeIgniter, this could be done with something like

```
$this->load->helper('string');
$tokenKey = random_string('alnum', 32);
$this->db->insert('tokens', array('userid' => $userid, 'key' => $tokenKey));
```

The `tokens` table should also contain a timestamp for when the token was created. This is because even though we add an expiration time to the cookie, this can still be fiddled with, so if we didn't have this double-checking, users could potentially gain permanent access to the page.

Now it's time to actually set the cookie. We set its expiration time to now + 3600 seconds (an hour from now).

```
setcookie('tokenKey', $tokenKey, time()+3600, '/');
```

Whenever a user tries to access your protected page, you could delete all tokens older than an hour (to make sure you don't have expired tokens stored), and then see if the token exists in your table. If it does, it's less than an hour old.

```
// delete old tokens
$tokenKey = $_COOKIE['tokenKey'];
// select token from database
```

Alternatively, you could have a cronjob or other scheduled event to clean up the expired tokens to save your clients from the extra time it'll take to delete old records. Depending on the size of your site, this time could be substantial.

Comment: None of this deals with "I'd want to either close the tab/window or send the user to another page".